# Здравствуйте, помогите сделать так чтобы карточки товара стояли в две колонки на против карты с фильтрами

Tags: html, bootstrap, handlebars

[![`

```html
<main>
    <div class="card mx-3 mt-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            {{#with navigation.links}}
                <div class="nav">
                    <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="{{0.href}}" class="nav-link">{{0.text}}</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="{{1.href}}" class="nav-link">{{1.text}}</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="{{1.href}}" class="nav-link disabled">{{1.text}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {{/with}}
        </div>
    </div>
{{!-- ================================================================================================= --}}
    {{#with breadcrumb}}
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb ms-3 mt-5">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{0.url}}">{{0.name}}</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{1.url}}">{{1.name}}</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a>{{2.name}}</a></li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    {{/with}}
{{!-- =================================================================================================== --}}
    <h1 class="ms-3 mt-5">{{header}}</h1>

    <div class="row">
  {{#each sortBlock}}
  <div class="col-3">
    <select class="form-select ms-3 mt-5">
      <option selected>{{placeholder}}</option>
      {{#each options}}
      <option value="{{value}}">{{text}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
{{!-- ==================================================================================================== --}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        {{#with filterBlock.sellers}}
            <div class="card ms-3 mt-5">
                <p class="ms-3 mt-2">{{title}}</p>

                {{#with list}}
                    <div class="form-check ms-3 mb-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                        <label class="form-check-label">{{0.value}}</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-check ms-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                        <label class="form-check-label">{{1.value}}</label>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="my-4 mx-3">
                {{/with}}
            {{/with}} 

            {{#with filterBlock.brands}}
                <p class="ms-3">{{title}}</p>
                <div class="col-11">
                    <input class="form-control ms-5 " placeholder="{{input.placeholder}}">
                </div>
            {{/with}}

            {{#with filterBlock.brands.options}}
            <div class="form-check ms-3 mt-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{0.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check ms-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{1.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check ms-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{2.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check ms-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{3.value}}</label>
            </div>
        {{/with}}

        <hr class="my-4 mx-3">
{{!-- ===================================================================================================== --}}

        {{#with filterBlock.price}}
            <div class="ms-3 mb-3">{{title}}</div>

            {{#with range}}
            <div class="col-11">
                <input class="form-control ms-5" placeholder="{{from}}">
                <input class="form-control ms-5" placeholder="{{to}}">
            </div>
            {{/with}}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="co-1">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary ms-5 mt-3" href="{{button.link}}">{{button.text}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/with}}

        <hr class="mx-3 my-4">

{{!-- ========================================================================================================================================== --}}

        {{#with filterBlock.filterList}}
            <div class="ms-3">{{0.title}}</div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input ms-3" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{0.options.0.value}}</label>
            </div>
        {{/with}}

        <hr class="mx-3 my-4">

{{!-- ======================================================================================================================================================== --}}

        {{#with filterBlock.filterList}}
            <div class="ms-3">{{1.title}}</div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{1.options.0.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{1.options.1.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{1.options.2.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{1.options.3.value}}</label>
            </div>
        {{/with}}

        <hr class="mx-3 my-4">
{{!-- ===================================================================================================== --}}

        {{#with filterBlock.filterList}}
            <div class="ms-3">{{2.title}}</div>

            <div class="form-check mt-3">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{2.options.0.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{2.options.1.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{2.options.2.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{2.options.3.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{2.options.4.value}}</label>
            </div>
        {{/with}}

        <hr class="mx-3 my-4">
{{!-- ========================================================================================================== --}}

        {{#with filterBlock.filterList}}
            <div class="ms-3">{{3.title}}</div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{3.options.0.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{3.options.1.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{3.options.2.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{3.options.3.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{3.options.4.value}}</label>
            </div>
        {{/with}}

        <hr class="mx-3 my-4">

{{!-- ====================================================================================================== --}}

        {{#with filterBlock.filterList}}
            <div class="ms-3">{{4.title}}</div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{4.options.1.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{4.options.2.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{4.options.3.value}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{4.options.4.value}}</label>
            </div>
        {{/with}}
        </div>
    </div>

    
    
    <div class="col-4">
    {{#with goodsList}}
    {{#each this}}
        <div class="card mt-5">
            <img src="{{img}}" class="card-img-top">

            <div class="card-title">
                {{#if isHot}}
                <div class="badge bg-warning rounded-pill">HOT!</div>
                {{/if}}

                {{#if isNew}}
                <div class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Нове!</div>
                {{/if}}

                <div>
                    {{#if isFast}}
                    <a class="btn btn-success">Швидка доставка!</a>
                    {{/if}}
                </div>

                <div>
                    {{#if isFree}}
                    <div class="btn btn-secondary">Бескоштовна доставка!</div>
                    {{/if}}
                </div>

                <h3 class="ms-2 mt-3">{{name}}</h3>
                <p>{{review.amount}} {{review.text}}</p>
                <b>{{price}}</b>
                <p>{{delivery}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
    </div>

    
    
 



</div>
</main>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]`][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMmVe.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMmVe.png)

Answer (score 0):

если ты заметишь то твои дизайн на фигме или фотошопе разделен розовыми столбиками и их там ровно 12, что отсылает тебя к гридам ибо там 12 колонок, как для новичка все это можно заверстать на бутстрапе ибо готовых примеров уйма.

[тык сюда](https://itchief.ru/bootstrap/grid-v4)